# PHP - Maximum size allowed for each element of array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, memory-leaks, floating-point

In my program I have 12 multidimensional arrays which their size vary between 200-7000. Each cell in array contains a float number with high precision (e.g. 0.0000000000000123344) and these arrays pass values to each other for some calculations. some times I get the error of lack of memory in some arrays (I have changed all configurations related to memory and it is set to maximum ). I'm wondering what is the maximum size allowed to store a float in a huge array? Thank you.

Comment: From the [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php): "*The size of a float is platform-dependent, although a maximum of ~1.8e308 with a precision of roughly 14 decimal digits is a common value (the 64 bit IEEE format).*"

Comment: But if you want to preserve the values with trailing zeroes etc., it might be better to store them as strings instead: `$arr = ['0.0000000000000123344', /* more values */];`.

Comment: I cant store them as string, I need to do calculation and comparisons using those float numbers

Comment: Did you look at `splFixedArray`?

Comment: Also you could read about size of PHP arrays: http://nikic.github.io/2011/12/12/How-big-are-PHP-arrays-really-Hint-BIG.html

Comment: @sectus: This question is about the length of a single element in an array, not the memory required to initialize the array.

Comment: @AmalMurali, did you read the link above?

Comment: @sectus: I've read it before. Did I miss anything?

Comment: @AmalMurali, there some infromation about `zval` size. Anyway, question has mentioning about `multidimensional arrays`, so size of array does matter. It's relative to the question but not directly, that is why this this a comment but not part of answer.

Comment: @sectus Thanks for your answers, in fact SplFixedArray is of fixed length and allows only integers within the range as indexes. I took a look at the link, it was quite helpful but still I need to know what is the maximum and minimum value of float which an element in an array may keep. If I know that, at least I can round all my numbers to the permitted limit to do not get the error anymore.\

Comment: It's double which always uses 64 bit to store number. From this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985 you could realise that it could store from ±2.23×10^−308 to ±1.80×10^308, approx. 15 decimal digits. Range or size of double value does not dependent on any array. It's just double.

Comment: cool, Im working with 32-bit WAMP Server , so I should foloow the 32 bits limit right ?

Comment: No. It's Double. It uses 64 bit for storing number.

Comment: Even If I round it to 15 decimal digits, still I have a problem with memory, when I limit the array to size of 900, I get no error, but more than 900, the system suffers from lack of memory it seems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I could find the solution. I found that when the PHP collection garbage is getting full, there is no way to free it. `Unset` and `gc_collect_cycles()` also are not effective. The only way is to use `**Function**` over different section of codes. In my case, I had a big script in a `for loop`, so I copied all my codes in a function, and in my loop I call the function. Each time function quiets, memory gets free. You may test it by adding `memory_get_usage()` once in your function and once out of the function to see the difference.